# CMD: How to echo special command symbol to clipboard?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to put this string `>>>` (it's just some handy copypaste) to clipboard. 
Since `>` is a special cmd-character, I'm using `^` before it to mean all special characters literally.

So far, my Batch code looks like this 
(`&& pause` here is used to see debug messages):

```
echo ^>^>^> && pause
echo ^>^>^>>"%~dp0foo.txt" && pause
echo foo|clip && pause
echo ^>^>^>|clip && pause
```

1st line works perfectly (not affecting clipboard though). 
2nd line works perfectly (not affecting clipboard either though). 
3rd line works perfectly (not using the symbols I need though). 
4th line returns `>> was unexpected at this time` error.

Obviously, I need some syntax tips.

Comment: Since a pipe (`|`) initiates a new `cmd.exe` instance per side, you need to double-escape: `echo ^^^>^^^>^^^>|clip && pause`

Comment: jeez; cmd surprises never dissapoint :) thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky, because the pipe creates two new cmd instances (like [@aschipf mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72459972/cmd-how-to-echo-special-command-symbol-to-clipboard/72461328#)).

You could use a variable and delayed expansion

```
set "var=>>>"
cmd /v:on /c "echo(!var!"| clip
```

Or you can use FOR-variable expansion

```
set "var=>>>"
( FOR %%X in ("%%var%%") DO @(echo(%%~X^) ) | clip
```

Comment: The space before the pipe was included in the string clipped for me. Removing it was successful.

Comment: @Magoo Thanks, I fixed the code. The second example already avoid the trailing space

Comment: I actually went with @aschipf one-liner, yet this answer sure is more general. Thank you, @jeb! Also, `echo(foostring` here once again seems to be the only correct form of `echo` command when applied to strings (unlike straightforward `echo foostring`, or any other).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured an almost decent workaround:

```
echo ^>^>^>>"%~dp0foo.txt"
type "%~dp0foo.txt"|clip
del "%~dp0foo.txt"
```

1. puts `>>>` into `foo.txt` right next to your Batch 
   (it also accounts for spaces in path to the file via `"`).
2. returns `>>>` as a content from `foo.txt` and puts it into clipboard.
3. deletes `foo.txt` right away.

Still hoping to meet a proper-syntax-based solution.